# Bulk change passwords

Tags: ubuntu, password-management, bulk-action

I am converting some scripts from an ancient SuSe install, after a swap to ubuntu. These scripts uses a tool called mkpasswd, which sets user passwords. I wonder if there is something similar for Ubuntu so I don't have to code it myself. The tool is very simple. It reads a file like

```
username1:password2
username2:password2
....
usernameN:passwordN
```

And sets the passwords on the users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chpasswd is very similar. Installed by default in ubuntu.

NAME
       chpasswd - update passwords in batch mode

SYNOPSIS
       chpasswd [options]

DESCRIPTION
       The chpasswd command reads a list of user name and password pairs from
       standard input and uses this information to update a group of existing
       users. Each line is of the format:

```
   user_name:password
```

Comment: I just found it myself ;) But thanks, it is indeed the right command.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has mkpasswd - you may need to install it by running `sudo aptitude install mkpasswd`.

Comment: Hmmm. "No candidate version found for mkpasswd" is what I get from that command. The only thing that seems to match is "libstring-mkpasswd-perl", and that does not seem to do what I want to do...

Comment: You need to enable the Universe repository first. See instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine#Adding the Universe and Multiverse Repositories

Comment: Still no luck with Universe and Multiverse enabled.

Comment: Did you type `sudo aptitude update` after enabling?